# Filter table with DNA sequences using pmatch [R]

Tags: r

I have a set of 17 tables(approx. [137520,1] each) with DNA reads that vary in length, which I am trying to filter according to the sequences found in them. I would like to get the proportions of reads containing sequence A, sequence B and other, respectively. Hence, I would like to loop over each of the reads and look for a partial match with the desired sequences.

```
Reads01[1:5,1]
[1] GAGAGGAGCCGGAAATCTGTTCTCGTTCAAGAAATTTGACGAGAA  
[2] GAGAGGAGCCGGAAATCTGACGAGAAGTTCAAGAAATTTGACGAGAA
[3] GAGAGGAGCCGGAAATCTGTTCTCGTTCAAGAATTTGACGAGAA   
[4] GAGAGGAGCCGGAAATCTGTTCTCGTTCAAGAAATTTGACGAGAA  
[5] GAGAGGAGCCGGAAATTTGACGAGAA   

> results01<-pmatch(KCCC01[,1], WTSeq, nomatch = NA_integer_, duplicates.ok = FALSE)
> results01[1:5]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

Even when I just look for a single letter (which should give a positive answer for all), I get NA.

```
> results01A<-pmatch(KCCC01[,1], "A", nomatch = NA_integer_, duplicates.ok = FALSE)
> results01A[1:5]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here, how can I solve this?

Comment: What's `WTSeq`? Also, please provide your desired output.

Comment: I don't think you're looking for `pmatch`. Try `grepl(WTSeq, KCCC01[,1])`, which will return a vector of logicals with the same size as `KCCC01[,1]` with `TRUE` for the elements which have `WTSeq`. You may also look at `?grep`